# Post String to a server

Tags: iphone, post, nsmutableurlrequest

i need to send this SomeString To a server by a post request.
 without to make it `NSData` object and do `NSUTF8StringEncoding` 
 the SetHttpBody: ask me only for a NSData object.
 how can i Post this String

```
SomeString = @"registerRecipt.aspx?udid=962c3486-a8d6-4c32-9ff8-7b255cce4d65&receipt=ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQW1wMnhiVGxYTGg5UmhFUUlCMzNLMHdZdHl3Tnd0WWFVaEdKQzNoUE04Rm8wSys4NE5wWkdWdWRFRndjQ0k3Q2draVluWnljeUlnUFNBaU1TNHdJanNLZlE9PSI7CgkiZW52aXJvbm1lbnQiID0gIlNhbmRib3giOwoJInBvZCIgPSAiMTAwIjsKCSJzaWduaW5nLXN0YXR1cyIgPSAiMCI7Cn0="

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someUrl.com/"]];
request.timeoutInterval = 20;
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:SomeString];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[SomeString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: i need to send string not databytes

Comment: When talking about networking (including HTTP), everything is just bytes. Only in the actual implementations (in your case, SomeString) they are strings, but after that they have to be converted to bytes and eventually back to strings when they are received. Depending on how you look at it, my code actually sent a string - it's simply represented as bytes.

Answer (score 0):

1. For easy development use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use)
2. your JSON in the Base64 String isnt valid.
3. UDID is deprecated use insted the mac adress from your iphone